# How to write a vector to a file with a function in C++?

Tags: c++

> Here are a few snippets of my code. First are my functions that I wrote. The one giving me an error is the fileout function, which is supposed to write the vector to a file.

```
vector<int> random(int rowsize, int columnsize) // generates a random matrix given number of rows and columns, stores it as a 1-dimensional vector
{
    int elements = rowsize*columnsize;
    vector<int> x(elements);
    int matrix[10][10];

    int n=0;
    for(int i = 0; i < rowsize; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < columnsize; j++)
                {
                    matrix[i][j]= -10 + rand() % 21;
                    x[n++] = matrix[i][j];
                }
            }

    return x;
}

void print(vector<int> matrix, int columnsize) //prints the matrix given the number of columns
{
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
    {
        if(i%columnsize != 0)
            cout << setw(10) << matrix[i];
        if(i%columnsize == 0)
            cout << endl << setw(10) << matrix[i];
    }
    cout << endl;
}

vector<int> addmat(vector<int> matrixA, vector <int> matrixB) //adds two matrices together, takes vector input
{
    vector<int> matrix(matrixA.size());
    for(int i=0; i< matrixA.size(); i++)
        matrix[i] = (matrixA[i] + matrixB[i]);

    return matrix;
}

vector<int> filefill(ifstream &fin, string file, int rowsize, int columnsize) //creates a matrix from a file
{
    fin.open(file.c_str());
    vector<int> matrix;
    int number;

    for(int i=0; i < rowsize*columnsize; i++)
    {
        while(fin >> number)
            matrix.push_back(number);
    }

    fin.close();
    return matrix;
}

void fileout(ofstream fout, string file, vector<int> matrix) //writes a matrix onto a file
{
    fout.open(file.c_str());
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
        fout << matrix[i];
    fout.close();
}
```

> This is the use of the function in the main. The fout inside the fileout function is marked as an error:
>
> "6 IntelliSense: "std::basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>::basic_ofstream(const std::basic_ofstream<_Elem, _Traits>::_Myt &_Right) [with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits]" (declared at line 1034 of "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\fstream") is inaccessible  c:\Users\William\Desktop\C++\Homework8\HW8\hw8.cpp  163 11  HW8

```
else if (answer == "N" || answer == "n")
    {

        matrixA = random (Arow, Acolumn);
        cout << "Matrix A" << endl;
        print(matrixA, Acolumn);

        matrixB = random (Brow, Bcolumn);
        cout << "Matrix B" << endl;
        print(matrixB, Bcolumn);

        cout << endl << "Matrix A + Matrix B =" << endl;

        vector<int> matrixC = addmat (matrixA, matrixB);
        print(matrixC, Acolumn);

        for (int i = 0; i < matrixA.size(); i++)
        {
            matrixB.push_back(matrixA[i]);
        }

        string filo;
        cin >> filo;
        ofstream fout;
        fileout(fout, filo, matrixB);


    }
```

> Not sure what the problem is????????????

Comment: Compare the signatures of `filefill`, where you take the stream by reference and `fileout`, where you take the stream by value.  Streams aren't value types meant to be copied around (and passing them by value to a function implies a copy of the value), they are meant to be passed by reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accepting an `ofstream` object from whoever calls the `fileout` function, try creating a local `ofstream fout` inside of `fileout`:

```
void fileout(string file, vector<int> matrix) //writes a matrix onto a file
{
    ofstream fout;
    fout.open(file.c_str());
    for(int i=0; i < matrix.size(); i++)
        fout << matrix[i];
    fout.close();
}
```